# Refresh indicator with a custom gif instead of a spinner

Tags: flutter, dart

Does anyone know how to make a Refresh indicator with a gif instead of a spinner?

Tried to make it with a [custom_refresh_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator) library

```
import 'package:custom_refresh_indicator/custom_refresh_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            height: 100,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: CustomRefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () => Future.delayed(
                const Duration(seconds: 3),
              ),
              builder: (
                context,
                child,
                controller,
              ) {
                return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: controller,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, _) {
                    return Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      children: [
                        if (!controller.isIdle)
                          Positioned(
                            top: -50,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 200,
                              width: 200,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/test.gif',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(0, 100.0 * controller.value),
                          child: child,
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return const Card(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: ListTile(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But it works very clumsily:

[image]

Also tried to look at [pull_to_refresh](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) library, but their Gif indicator example is very unclear and outdated.

So anyone knows any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to achieve this using the previously mentioned **[custom_refresh_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_refresh_indicator)** package.

##### Code

```dart
class ImageIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The image to be displayed as an indicator.
  final ImageProvider image;

  /// The callback that will be triggered as a result
  /// of the pull-to-refresh gesture.
  final AsyncCallback onRefresh;

  /// A scrollable widget, such as [ListView].
  final Widget child;

  const ImageIndicator({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.image,
    required this.onRefresh,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomRefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: onRefresh,
      child: child,
      /// We use the [MaterialIndicatorDelegate] class, which simulates
      /// the behavior of the built-in [RefreshIndicator] widget container.
      builder: MaterialIndicatorDelegate(
        /// We can make some adjustments to the default material container
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        builder: (context, controller) {
          /// This is the interesting part!
          /// Here you specify the content of the custom refresh indicator.
          return Image(
            image: image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

##### Effect using a random gif from Google images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/64oQ9.gif

---

ℹ️ Of course, instead of an image, you can use the widget of your choice or even get rid of the `MaterialIndicatorDelegate` and build your own indicator from scratch .